# Modifying Hippo cnd file

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

I'm modifying some default cnd files in my Hippo CMS project.
When I upload a new cnd to the console, autoexport works and creates a new .cnd file in my bootstrap configuration module.

This happens with all cnd files but hippo.cnd.

I manually created a hippo.cnd file in my bootstrap module and removed my local repository. But when I restarted the project all cnd were initialized well but hippo.cnd.

Does somebody have a solution for bootstraping hippo.cnd file?

Comment: Why do you need a modified hippo.cnd file? What's the use case?

Comment: I want to save my images and assets in an S3 storage. So I added a property to the hippo:resource type to save its key in the S3 storage.
For the images I could edit the hippogallery:image type, but for the assets I needed to edit the hippo:resource type, that is located in hippo.cnd

Comment: In that case you could have created your own custom type in your own namespace that extended the type defined in your hippo.cnd. Alternatively you could have used the S3 datastore implementation in Jackrabbit. Do keep in mind that this is as far as I know not officially supported by Hippo.

Comment: I tried to extend the type hippo:resource defined in hippo.cnd. But one of the things I want to do is to make jcr:data property not mandatory. I tried to override the property but I got an error. Maybe I had to create my own "resource" type. For the moment I'm going to modify hippo.cnd file and import content manually after each installation.

Comment: I didn't know about Jackrabbit S3 datastore, thank you Jeroen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hippo.cnd file is a system based CND file. You should never have to change that file, because you can always create types that extend the default hippo nodetypes. The reason it does not reload properly is, because the repository is loading the hippo.cnd file when it starts. During the starting phase it checks if there is an existing repository. If not it will bootstrap the internal hippo.cnd file.